# Searching a Text File and Returning array in Java

Tags: java, program-entry-point, bufferedreader, readline

My project for programming class is to create a program (using NetBeans) where users may enter Movie Information and store it. They are able to Search the list of movies for information, ie title, actor, quality etc. I have a java file that allows users to enter information about the movie in textfields and it saves it to a txt file.

The problem I am having is that everytime the user searches for the movie, it returns a null pointer exception.

Here is the part of my code for searching:

```
private void sbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    try{
        if(!mField.getText().equals("Search Movie Title")){
            if(sameTitle(mField.getText())!=null){
                display_Search_Info.main(info);
                dispose();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Movie Info Found.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        if(!aField.getText().equals("Search Actor Name")){
            if(sameActor(aField.getText())!=null){
                display_Search_Info.main(info);
                dispose();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Movie Info Found.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        if(!gBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Genre")){
            if(sameGenre(String.valueOf(gBox.getSelectedItem()))!=null){
                display_Search_Info.main(info);
                dispose();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Movie Info Found.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        if(!lBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Location")){
            if(sameLocation(String.valueOf(lBox.getSelectedItem()))!=null){
                display_Search_Info.main(info);
                dispose();
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Movie Info Found.", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        if(mField.getText().equals("Search Movie Title")&&aField.getText().equals("Search Actor Name")&&gBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Genre")&&lBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Select Location")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Enter Information About The Movie", "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);                
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error Occured");
    }    
}                                    
public String[] sameTitle(String s) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("M:/NetBeans Projects/MovieList/src/MovieInfo.txt"));
    String line;
    info= new String[6];
    do{
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            info[i]=br.readLine();
        }
    }while((line=br.readLine())!=null);

    if(info[0].contains(s)){
        return info;
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}
public String[] sameActor(String s) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("M:/NetBeans Projects/MovieList/src/MovieInfo.txt"));
    String line="";
    info= new String[6];
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null&&!info[1].contains(s)||!info[2].contains(s)){
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            info[i]=br.readLine();
        }
    }
    if(info[1].contains(s)||info[2].contains(s)){
        return info;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
public String[] sameGenre (String s) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("M:/NetBeans Projects/MovieList/src/MovieInfo.txt"));
    String line="";
    info= new String[6];
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null&&!info[3].contains(s)){
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            info[i]=br.readLine();
        }
    }
    if(info[3].contains(s)){
        return info;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
public String[] sameLocation (String s) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("M:/NetBeans Projects/MovieList/src/MovieInfo.txt"));
    String line="";
    info= new String[6];
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null&&!info[4].contains(s)){
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            info[i]=br.readLine();
        }
    }
    if(info[4].contains(s)){
        return info;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

The jOptionPane does not work and it does not send it to the next file just simply getting
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException".

Comment: Include the exception stack trace as well.

Comment: Without the stacktrace, it's not possible to tell, but here is some general advice: If you are comparing a hardcoded-string to a variable string, put the hardcoded one first, IE: `"Search Movie Title".equals(mField.getText())`  The other way around could cause a NPE if the variable/field is not initialized properly.

Comment: i did it the other way because NetBeans always says it is more logical to do it as the textfield first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your methods seem to have the "same" structure, I suggest you use a List to store your matching line(s). That is, I think you should try something more like this -

```
public String[] sameLocation(String s) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "M:/NetBeans Projects/MovieList/src/MovieInfo.txt"));
    String line = "";
    List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (s != null) {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // <-- Why 6?
                al.add(line);
            }
        }
    }
    if (al.size() > 0) {
        String [] out = new String[al.size()];
        return al.toArray(out);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, everything works now. Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it.